# toggle class content on click from nav

Tags: javascript, html, css, onclick

I have a simple page with 15 elements in the Nav bar (only 4 in the jsfiddle example to keep the code short).

I have a javascript that moves the border-bottom display on click on the nav bar elements but I would also like the content of the div underneath to change based on which nabber item is clicks.

This is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uun45o5j/8/).

Ive tried getElementByID but I somehow cant seem to change the class under my #tabs-content div... 
I would like a javascript loop that changes the content of each section element's class from hide to show or show to hide depending on what the content is.

This is the o'clock event in my

```
<li class="tab-current"><a href="#section1" onclick="display(section1) class="icon icon-dash"><span>Dashboard</span></a></li>
```

and I would like it to change the class from hide to show for id=section2 and from show to hide for section2:

```
<div id="tabs-content">
    <section id="section1" class="show">
        <p>1</p>
    </section>
    <section id="section2" class="hide">
        <p>2</p>
    </section>
</div>
```

Any ideas please?

Cheers,
M.

Comment: Not an answer, but.. - You're missing the closing quotes on `onclick="display(section1)`

Comment: well there is that too! lol thanks for spotting this :)

Comment: You haven't defined a `display()` function

Comment: I know, that's the bit Im struggling with as my knowledge of JS is extremely limited. I know I need a loop and for each I need to change the content of the class under #tabs-content... Im just struggling with actually writing that function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for? Since you have the `id` of each `section` in the `href` you can pull that to load the appropriate one:

JS

```
var currentTab = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
$(currentTab).show().siblings("section").hide();
```

Change CSS (unless you want the elements to take up space on the page its better to set to display: none):

```
#tabs-content section.show {
  display: block
}

#tabs-content section.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/uun45o5j/10/)

Comment: that's not what I had in mind to get it working as I thought Id need a loop to change the class content of each section element but that works brilliantly in just two lines :) that's spot on what I wanted :) Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Mickael no problem. Glad to help. Just be sure to check this off as completed.

Comment: I did... but the site said I had to wait 10 minutes to tick it as accepted :)